# Same origin policy, which properties are writable besides location?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, iframe, same-origin-policy

Look at the following code:

```
<iframe src="http://google.com" name="google" style="height:100px"></iframe>

<script> 
document.getElementsByName('google')[0].onload = function() {
  try {
    alert(frames[0].location)
  } catch(e) {
    alert("Error: "+e)
  }
}
</script>
```

Browser protects `location` property from being read. However,it allows to 
write that property:

```
<script> 
document.getElementsByName('google')[0].onload = function() {
  frames[0].location = 'http://wikipedia.org'
  alert('Changed to wikipedia')
}
</script>
```

(code examples are taken from http://javascript.info/tutorial/same-origin-security-policy)

The question is which other properties are writable in the same way as `location` is.

Comment: 3rd google result: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy#Cross-origin_script_API_access

Comment: Shame on stupid me. 
Thanks alot!